# Cant save user input from radio button in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have retrieve data from lvl1itquepaper and display it with 4 radio button and save the user input to another table call lvl1itresult but when I press save, no matter which option I choose, the answer that will be saved into database sure is option 4 even if the student select other option.

```
<?php
        include('../dbconnect.php');
        session_start();
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Online Examination System</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="container">
    <h1>Level 1 IT Question Paper</h1>
    <h2>Please read the question carefully and answer it confidently. Good Luck All!</h2>


        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
        {
            $sql="SELECT * from lvl1itquepaper";
        $run_que = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $check_que = mysqli_num_rows($run_que);

            while ($row=$run_que->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $questionno = $row['questionno'];
                $question = $row['question'];
                $option1 = $row['option1'];
                $option2 = $row['option2'];
                $option3 = $row['option3'];
                $option4 = $row['option4'];
                $ans_array = array($option1, $option2, $option3, $option4);
                $student_ans = $row['option1'];
                $student_ans = $row['option2'];
                $student_ans = $row['option3'];
                $student_ans = $row['option4'];

                $sql="Insert into lvl1itresult (questionno, question, studentans, username) values ('.$questionno.', '$question', '$student_ans', '".$_SESSION['login_user']."')";

            $submit = $mysqli->query($sql);
        }
        }

        ?>




        <form method= "post">
    <?php
        echo "Welcome, ";
        $sql="SELECT * from lvl1itstudent WHERE username= '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'";
        $find_student = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $check_student = mysqli_num_rows($find_student);
            if ($check_student>0){
                while($row = $find_student->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo $row['username'];
                }
            }
        echo "<br><br><br><br>";

        $sql="SELECT * from lvl1itquepaper";
        $run_que = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $check_que = mysqli_num_rows($run_que);

        if($check_que>0){
            while ($row=$run_que->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $questionno = $row['questionno'];
                $question = $row['question'];
                $option1 = $row['option1'];
                $option2 = $row['option2'];
                $option3 = $row['option3'];
                $option4 = $row['option4'];
                $ans_array = array($option1, $option2, $option3, $option4);
                shuffle($ans_array);

                echo "".$questionno. "." .$question."<br>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='.$questionno.' value='".$ans_array[0]."'>".$ans_array[0]."<br>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='.$questionno.' value='".$ans_array[1]."'>".$ans_array[1]."<br>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='.$questionno.' value='".$ans_array[2]."'>".$ans_array[2]."<br>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='.$questionno.' value='".$ans_array[3]."'>".$ans_array[3]."<br><br>";
            }

        }
        else {
            echo "there is no data in database";
        }

        ?>


       <input type="submit" value = "Submit" name= "Submit" style= "width:60px; height:30px";>


        </form>


    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: is there multiple questions comes in while loop with multiple options for every question?

Comment: ya there are multiple question that retrieve from lvl1itquepaper and each question with 4 option(4 radio button).

Answer (score 0):

```
$student_ans = $row['option1'];
$student_ans = $row['option2'];
$student_ans = $row['option3'];
$student_ans = $row['option4'];
```

Because of this, you keep pointlessly overwriting the same variable. You should only store the option they selected in `$student_ans`.

You may want to review your logic a bit, you're moving things in and out of arrays and different variables for no reason.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you tell me how to improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

Do slight modification to form

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='qno' value='".$questionno."'";
echo "<input type='radio' name='ans' value='".$ans_array[0]."'>".$ans_array[0]."<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='ans' value='".$ans_array[1]."'>".$ans_array[1]."<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='ans' value='".$ans_array[2]."'>".$ans_array[2]."<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='ans' value='".$ans_array[3]."'>".$ans_array[3]."<br><br>";
```

and then on posting form fetch them using:

`$_POST['ans']` for answer field and `$_POST['qno']` for question

This way you will only have the option selected by student

Comment: thank you for your reply but i dont really understand the method you do.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing when `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` is true

Comment: retrieve information from lvl1itquepaper then when press submit button then save to lvl1itresult

Comment: Don't fetch values from database when sumit is set. Only get values posted in the form and insert it into database.

Comment: Due to my system requirement, admin can upload question into database with question number, question and option 1 to option 4. So when student login, it need to retrieve the question from database and save into another table

Comment: I don't get your logic